# App started running slow without any changes on code

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

So, yesterday my app was running fine, but today it started to run really slow for no reason.

I've been trying to find the cause using  **CACurrentMediaTime()** and now I know that its between **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** on **AppDelegate** and my **viewDidLoad** of my first ViewController.

From here on it always takes about 10 seconds to load any new View, but inside the view it runs fluid.

I can post my logs here:

> app[311:25582] 4665.159450
>
> app[311:25582] Splash - 4673.318206

[image: First image]

[image: Second image]

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSLog(@"%@",[paths objectAtIndex:0]);
     NSLog(@"%f", CACurrentMediaTime());
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not enough information to answer.

Comment: What you need me to add?

Comment: No idea.  You could run it in Instruments and see if that shows anything.

Comment: already done it, takes 10 seconds to load the Splash and CPU gets to 90%, then again other 10 seconds to my second view

Comment: Assuming your phone runs other apps normally, the logical conclusion is that something in your code is making it run slowly. Since you haven't posted any of your code, no one can possibly help you.

Comment: the main problem is that yesterday I had the app running fine on my phone, and today, without changing anything, this happened. So i don't think it can be from any code that I've done.

Comment: Instruments will let you drill down to see details about where your code is spending it's time.

Comment: I've added the reports. I'm somewhat new to iOS, sorry if its obvious

Comment: Can you specify what actions are performing in application didFinishLauncing: callback.

Comment: I've added didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by deleting the ViewController and creating a new one.

What I did to find the possible cause of the problem:

1. Went to an older version of the app to see it running (it was running ok)
2. Copied the Storyboard to the old project (started to run slow again)
3. Copied only the ViewController (again, it was running slow)
4. Copied only view by view (it worked!!)

My guess is that the ViewController was with some error and was messing up the rest of the app.

Just posting here the answer so that I can help someone else.

Comment: From what you write I can hypothesize that you had layout constraints which failed on the slow version of your view controller, e.g.: Cannot satisfy all constraints in view X, had to relax constraint xyz ...

Comment: @user4839438 to be fair, I did mess up with the view controller, but thought I undid everything, so I cant confirm that to you, sorry